# HTML - Como mostrar/esconder conteúdos ao clicar em um "link"?

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web, script

Preciso montar um FAQ nesse estilo:
[image: EXEMPLO DO FAQ]

Clico na pergunta, ela apresenta a resposta ao lado. Se eu clico em outra pergunta, a resposta deve alternar e mostrar a resposta referente a outra pergunta clicada.
Como posso fazer isso? Pelo o que pesquisei notei que preciso de um script, mas acabei de começar a aprender html justamente por conta do trabalho, então não conheço muito.. Alguma ideia?

Comment: Então, utilizam javascript para isso, ficaria tipo "ao clicar no texto com o id tal, aparece no campo o texto tal", html não faz isso já que é só uma linguagem de marcação. ---------- Você poderia fazer utilizando jQuery também (o que eu acredito ser mais fácil, já que jQuery é uma biblioteca do javascript simplificada).
Se não conhece nenhum dos dois, sugiro começar pelo javascript, para você ter uma noção do que é, e depois usar jquery.
[Curso de JavaScript (videoaula)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZOvW-GK5fQ), ou [esse aqui, que está em inglês, mas que explica bem detalhado sobre tudo](

Comment: Um dos primeiros passos de quem está iniciando, e tomar cuitado para não reinventar a roda. Já ouviu falar em bootsrap?  Aqui um exemplo do que você quer: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp.  Recomendo você ler: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp.

Comment: Tem que ser exatamente no lado?

Comment: Sim, precisa ser exatamente do lado

Comment: Obrigado GabrielRodrigues  e MarcosMarques pelos links de referência e dicas! Comecei a ler e estou entendendo, vai ajudar bastante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue um pequeno exemplo de como fazer:

```js
function mostraResposta(id){
  respostas = document.getElementsByClassName('faq'); //recupera todos elementos da classe faq
  for (var i = 0; i < respostas.length; i++) { // coloca todos eles invisiveis
    respostas[i].style.display = 'none'; 
  }
  
  clicada = document.getElementById(id); //recupera o id passado por argumento
  clicada.style.display = 'inherit'; //faz ele ser exibido conforme o item pai
}
```

```css
#links {
  float: left;
  max-width: 50%; 
}
#links li {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#links li:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#respostas {
  float: right;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.faq {
  margin: 20px;
  display: none; /* coloca todos como invisiveis inicialmente */
}
```

```html
<div id="conteudo">
  <div id="links">
    <ul>
      <li onclick="mostraResposta('lorem')">Lorem</li>
      <li onclick="mostraResposta('ipsum')">Ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="respostas">
  <div id="lorem" class="faq">Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem </div>
  <div id="ipsum" class="faq">Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum
  Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum
  Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum
  Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Legal, obrigado!

Comment: Que bom, Setinha pra cima então!

Comment: Minha reputação ta baixa ainda kkkk ele não marca, mas eu votei!

Comment: Agora consegue.

Comment: Aee, valeu cara!